# Creating a form with a certain amount of numbers in it

Tags: javascript, forms, numbers, restriction

Hi there i have this script and im trying to make it work so that only a certain amount of numbers (8 numbers) are allowed in it. What do i have to add to this??

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">

function numbersonly(myfield, e, dec)
{
var key;
var keychar;

if (window.event)
   key = window.event.keyCode;
else if (e)
   key = e.which;
else
   return true;
keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

// control keys
if ((key==null) || (key==0) || (key==8) || 
    (key==9) || (key==13) || (key==27) )
   return true;

// numbers
else if ((("0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1))
   return true;

// decimal point jump
else if (dec && (keychar == "."))
   {
   myfield.form.elements[dec].focus();
   return false;
   }
else
   return false;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either add the attribute **size** (size="8") to your field directly or do it using JS :

```
var sizeLimitation = document.createAttribute('size');
sizeLimitation.value = 8;
myfield.setAttributeNode(sizeLimitation);
```